# Show text dropdown button with JavaScript in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I want to show my text in dropdown radio button like this:

[image]

but, my radio button error and nothing happen in my dropdown radio button:

[image]

How can I achieve this dropdown radio button? This is my code in view

```html
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown dropdown-full-width dropdown-category">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span class="name">
              <span id="category-select">Choose Category</span>
          </span>
          <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <li><strong>By {{ $category[1] }}</strong></li>
      @foreach($category1 as $occasions)
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="radio" name="category['occasions']" class="category-radio" value="{{ $occasions->id }}"> {{ $occasions->name }}</label>
        </div>
      </li>
      @endforeach
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <li><strong>By {{ $category[2] }}</strong></li>
      @foreach($category2 as $types)
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="radio" name="category['types']" class="category-radio" value="{{ $types->id }}"> {{ $types->name }}</label>
        </div>
      </li>
      @endforeach
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <li><strong>By {{ $category[3] }}</strong></li>
      @foreach($category3 as $flowers)
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="radio" name="category['flowers']" class="category-radio" value="{{ $flowers->id }}"> {{ $flowers->name }}</label>
        </div>
      </li>
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.category-radio').change(function() {
    var category_occasions = $('input[name="category[\'occasions\']"]:checked').text() || '';
    var category_types = $('input[name="category[\'types\']"]:checked').text() || '';
    var category_flowers =$('input[name="category[\'flowers\']"]:checked').text() || '';
    var output = category_occasions + ((category_occasions && category_types) ? ' - ' : '') + category_types + ((category_types && category_flowers) ? ' - ' : '') + category_flowers;
    $('#category-select').text(output);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is really with Javascript/JQuery and you can simplify your problem to that.

In this case, you are requesting the `text()` of the checkbox, but in fact, it's the label that holds the value you are after:

```
var category_occasions = $('input[name="category[\'occasions\']"]:checked').parent().text() || '';
```

And an example:

```js
$('.category-radio').change(function() {
  var category_occasions = $('input[name="category[\'occasions\']"]:checked').parent().text().trim() || '';
  var category_types = $('input[name="category[\'types\']"]:checked').parent().text().trim() || '';
  var category_flowers = $('input[name="category[\'flowers\']"]:checked').parent().text().trim() || '';
  var output = category_occasions + ((category_occasions && category_types) ? ' - ' : '') + category_types + ((category_types && category_flowers) ? ' - ' : '') + category_flowers;
  $('#category-select').text(output);
  console.log(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" name="category['occasions']" class="category-radio" value="birthday" />
 Birthday</label>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" name="category['types']" class="category-radio" value="birthday" />
Bouqet</label>
    <label>
          <input type="radio" name="category['flowers']" class="category-radio" value="birthday" />
Daisies</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Jquery **parent()** or **closest('label')** to select your element and you can easily get text with **text()**.

Look at the snippet down.

```js
$('.category-radio').change(function() {
    var category_occasions = $('input[name="category[\'occasions\']"]:checked').parent().text();
    var category_types = $('input[name="category[\'types\']"]:checked').parent().text();
    var category_flowers = $('input[name="category[\'flowers\']"]:checked').parent().text();
    
    var output = category_occasions + ((category_occasions && category_types) ? ' - ' : '') + category_types + ((category_types && category_flowers) ? ' - ' : '') + category_flowers;
    $('#category-select').text(output);
});
```

```html
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown dropdown-full-width dropdown-category">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span class="name">
              <span id="category-select">Choose Category</span>
          </span>
          <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <li><strong>By Occasions</strong></li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="radio" name="category['occasions']" class="category-radio" value="0">Anniversaries</label>
          <label><input type="radio" name="category['occasions']" class="category-radio" value="1">Birthdays</label>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <li><strong>By Types</strong></li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="radio" name="category['types']" class="category-radio" value="0">Baskets</label>
          <label><input type="radio" name="category['types']" class="category-radio" value="0">Hampers</label>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <li><strong>By Flowers</strong></li>
      <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="radio" name="category['flowers']" class="category-radio" value="0">Roses</label>
          <label><input type="radio" name="category['flowers']" class="category-radio" value="0">Tulips</label>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```